# How to remove only rows which has null values in mongodb in a single query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection **test** with a record :

```
[{ number:"1524",
name:null,
cat_id:"126842"},
{number:"456",
name:null,
cat_id:null }]
```

How to remove the whole row having null values like this :

```
[{ number:"1524",
 cat_id:"126842" },
{ number:"456"}]
```

I tried this but whole records are getting deleted rather than just the rows.

```
collection.deleteMany( { $or: [{cat_id : null },{ name : null }]
```

**Need to remove multiple variables in a single query.**

MongoDB version 4.0

Answer (score 2):

> In MongoDB, the $unset operator is used to delete a particular field.

You can try using the following commands to delete field that are empty

```
collection.updateMany({name: null}, { $unset : { name : 1 }})
```

This command will delete the **name** field from all documents where name is `null`. You can do a similar command for cat_id as well.

**Edit :** As per an answer received by me in another question I asked, You can also do the same in a single command using the following way -

```
collection.updateMany({
  $or : [{
    name : null
  }, {
    cat_id : null
  }]
}, [{
  $set: {
    name : { $ifNull : ["$hobby", "$$REMOVE"] },
    cat_id : { $ifNull : ["$Roll_no", "$$REMOVE"] }
  }
}]
);
```

However, this can only be done in MongoDb V4.2 and above. You can also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49551130/mongodb-remove-null-fields-recursively) for another way of doing it.

Hope it helps !

Comment: can we do it in a single db call ?

Comment: I thought of mentioning it in answer, but I am not absolutely sure about it.

Comment: can we try that with $or ?

Comment: @sigmoidnuetron We can't use it in the same way. check the edit I made and see if it helps