# Mongo 4.2: Remove Null fields

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nosql, mongo-shell

Documents in my MongoDB collection look like this:

My Mongo version is 4.2.3

```
{
            "_id": "SAGE-UW-00005",
            "carriers": [
                {
                    "bindable": true,
                    "carrierCode": "LMICO",
                    "mapped": true,
                    "products": [
                        {
                            "industries": [
                                {
                                    "industryCode": null,
                                     "states": "GA"
                                }
                            ],
                            "isAllNCCIValid": null,
                            "isAllstateValid": true,
                            
                        }
                    ],
                    "questionCode": "LMGENRL17"
                }
            ],
            "column": 1,
            "dataType": null,
            
    }
```

This is my desired output:

```
{
        "_id": "SAGE-UW-00005",
        "carriers": [
            {
                "bindable": true,
                "carrierCode": "LMICO",
                "mapped": true,
                "products": [
                    {
                        "industries": [
                            {
                          
                                 "states": "GA"
                            }
                        ],
      
                        "isAllstateValid": true,
                        
                    }
                ],
                "questionCode": "LMGENRL17"
            }
        ],
        "column": 1,
     
        
    }
```

I am not sure the depth of nested subdocuments in the collection, but there should be a lot of null fields in the collection. My backend code uses $exists to query the fields in the collection, so null is creating a problem here.

Comment: Are you looking for [Remove all fields that are null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287204/remove-all-fields-that-are-null)

Comment: @Gibbs, yes. The solution in the  link doesn't seem to be working for me,

Comment: In general, you need to know the fields you are trying to update (or remove). That will make your task easier. There are features like [Aggregation Updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/index.html) and [Array Update Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/update-array/index.html) you can take advantage of.

Comment: @prasad_ gotcha. Will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure the depth of nested subdocuments in the collection, but there should be a lot of null fields in the collection

It is a dynamic question. Best option would be replace the document after removing null fields in the code.

As you have nested levels, I would suggest you to map your data to `pojo` and check whether any entry and field is null.  Unless you aware of the fields, it is not efficient to remove them.