# Or with If and In mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
{
  $cond: {
    if: { $in: [`$$${field.fieldName}`, ['', null]] },
    then: [],
    else: `$$${field.fieldName}`,
  },
},
```

In this condition, I also want to check the field.fieldName exits.

`$exists: true,`

then it will something like

`if ( !filed.fieldName || field.fieldName === null || field.fieldName === '') then []`

I am not finding any way to add `$exits: true` or `false` in this.
Please help if can add something to this. Or any alternate way to achieve ?

Comment: there is no need of exists condition because if filled does not exist then it will return null, so your null condition is enough. see working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z7uZac6pezT), your condition is perfect.

Comment: @turivishal, but in case of non-existing field, he wants `[]` as result, not `null`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, I think the else part removes the field when it does not exist, so he wants to prevent that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put `$ifNull` in else part, if it's not exists it will return `[]`,

```
{
  $cond: {
    if: {
      $in: [`$$${field.fieldName}`, ["", null]]
    },
    then: [],
    else: { $ifNull: [`$$${field.fieldName}`, []] }
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f2-Is_dKosN)

Input:

```
[
  { "key": null },
  { "key": "" },
  { "A": "a" }
]
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "key": null,
    "status": []
  },
  {
    "key": "",
    "status": []
  },
  {
    "status": []
  }
]
```

---

Second approach, if you want to add an existing condition in `if` part you can try condition with `$or`,

- `$type` will return the field's data type the missing field type is "missing"

```
{
  $cond: {
    if: {
      $or: [
        { $eq: [{ $type: `$$${field.fieldName}` }, "missing"] },
        { $in: [`$$${field.fieldName}`, ["", null]] }
      ]
    },
    then: [],
    else: `$$${field.fieldName}`
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5EiH_g846ll)

Answer (score 3):

Bear in mind, "*field.fieldName exists*" might be different to "*field.fieldName is not null*".

Consider special values like this:

```
db.collection.insertMany([
  { _id: 1, a: 1 }, 
  { _id: 2, a: '' }, 
  { _id: 3, a: undefined }, 
  { _id: 4, a: null }, 
  { _id: 5 }
])
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         type: { $type: "$a" },
         ifNull: { $ifNull: ["$a", true] },
         defined: { $ne: ["$a", undefined] },
         existing: { $ne: [{ $type: "$a" }, "missing"] }
      }
   }   
])


{ _id: 1, a: 1,         type: "double",    ifNull: 1,    defined: true,  existing: true }
{ _id: 2, a: "",        type: "string",    ifNull: "",   defined: true,  existing: true }
{ _id: 3, a: undefined, type: "undefined", ifNull: true, defined: false, existing: true }
{ _id: 4, a: null,      type: "null",      ifNull: true, defined: true,  existing: true }
{ _id: 5,               type: "missing",   ifNull: true, defined: false, existing: false }
```

So, condition could be this one, depending on your requirements:

```
{
   $cond: {
      if: { $ne: [{ $type: "$field.fieldName" }, "missing"] },
      then: [],
      else: "$field.fieldName",
   }
}
```

For sake of completeness: With `db.collection.find()`:

```
db.collection.find({ a: { $exists: false } })
  { _id: 5 }

db.collection.find({ a: { $exists: true} })
  { _id: 1, a: 1 }, 
  { _id: 2, a: '' }, 
  { _id: 3, a: undefined }, 
  { _id: 4, a: null }

db.collection.find({ a: null })
  { _id: 3, a: undefined }, 
  { _id: 4, a: null },
  { _id: 5 }

db.collection.find({ a: {$ne: null} })
  { _id: 1, a: 1 }, 
  { _id: 2, a: '' }, 

db.collection.find({ a: {$type: "null"} })
  { _id: 4, a: null }
```

Comment: Three dollars working fine. I am writing dynamic pipeline code. Just wanted to add $exits.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

[$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)

> Evaluates an expression and returns the value of the expression if the expression evaluates to a non-null value. If the expression evaluates to a null value, including instances of undefined values or missing fields, returns the value of the replacement expression.

`{ $ifNull: [ <expression>, <replacement-expression-if-null> ] }`

```
{
    $cond: {
      if: { 
        $or : [
            { $in: [`$$${field.fieldName}`, ['', null]] },
            { $ifNull: [`$$${field.fieldName}`, ""] }
        ]},
      then: [],
      else: `$$${field.fieldName}`,
    }
},
```

Comment: I don't think $ifNull condition needed, because if field does not exist it will return null, i think OP's query is perfect. you can check playground that i attached in above comment.

Comment: @turivishal oh yes my bad, didn't notice that. Thank you. I think `$ifNull` will help OP .

Comment: you are right, I think this is a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{
  $cond: {
    if: { $ne : [`$$${field.fieldName}`, undefined] },
    then: [],
    else: `$$${field.fieldName}`,
  },
}
```