# Mongo field null vs empty

Tags: mongodb, go

SQL has the convention of leaving fields as null when not present.

Is there a convention in Mongo to leave the field as null or use an empty value (such as an empty array) if the field is not set?

To be specific, I am using Go and Mongo 4.2 with the [official Go mongo driver](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver).

For example,

```golang
type A struct {
    ID string `bson:"_id"`

    Bs []B `bson:"bs"`
}

type B struct {
    ID string `bson:"_id"`
}
```

If an `A` does not have any `B`s (`Bs` is empty), should it be defined as a zero-value (`[]B(nil)`) or as an empty array (`[]B{}`).

Note this affects the way the data is stored:

for zero-value

```json
{
    "_id" : ...,
    "bs" : null
}
```

vs for empty value

```json
{
    "_id" : ...,
    "bs" : [ ]
}
```

As well as construction before `InsertOne` (or insertion in general), since you would want to make sure memory is allocated beforehand for such objects.

Comment: There are even more than "null" and "empty": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68255363/or-with-if-and-in-mongodb/68255564#68255564

Answer (score 1):

In GO a string can not be null but a pointer to a string can be null so just use a pointer.