# In updateMany, update the field only if field exists, and do not create a new key

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

So what I want to do inside the $set is check if the field exists and then update the value, but only if this field exists. The $cond is very close to what I want to achieve but the problem is I can't stop it from creating the field.

I could filter to get only the existing field, but in this case I would have to update field by field instead of all at the same time, and this would take forever.

```js
 const data = await connection.collection("snapshot").updateMany({}, [
    {
      $set: {
        field1: {
          $cond: [
            { field1: { $exists: true } },
            { field1: "newValue" },
            undefined, // do nothing
          ],
        },
        field2: {
          $cond: [
            { field2: { $exists: true } },
            { field2: "newValue" },
            undefined, // do nothing
          ],
        },
        field3: {
          $cond: [
            { field3: { $exists: true } },
            { field3: "newValue" },
            undefined, // do nothing
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  ]);
```

Am I missing something or is just impossible to do?

I'm using mongo 5.0

Comment: good to add example document ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator `$exists` works only in `find`, not in Aggregation Pipelines. Checking for "field exists" is not trivial, see [Or with If and In mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68255363/or-with-if-and-in-mongodb/68255564#68255564)

I assume you like to update documents like `{ field3: "newValue" }`, your update will do `{ field3: { field3: "newValue" } }`

Over all it would be this one:

```
connection.collection("snapshot").updateMany({}, [
   {
      $set: {
         field1: {
            $cond: [
               { $ne: [{ $type: "$field1" }, "missing"] },
               "newValue",
               "$$REMOVE" // do nothing
            ]
         },
         field2: {
            $cond: [
               { $ne: [{ $type: "$field2" }, "missing"] },
               "newValue",
               "$$REMOVE" // do nothing
            ]
         },
         field3: {
            $cond: [
               { $ne: [{ $type: "$field3" }, "missing"] },
               "newValue",
               "$$REMOVE" // do nothing
            ]
         }
      }
   }
])
```