# In MongoDB, is there any difference between not storing a field and storing that field as null?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{
  A: 1
  B: null
}
```

vs

```
{
  A: 1
}
```

Is there any differences between the 2 documents?

Comment: yes its not the same, those documents are not equal also. but people use both, one difference as far as i know is that if we index the B field, we can find the documents with B=null fast, the second needs exists false and i think cant be indexed to retrieve it fast . So if you care about indexing the B and find those that have missing B i think its best to use the first one, but i am not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is a difference. Document with `B: null` consumes little more space on your disk. Also if you like to query them, they are different, see [Or with If and In mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68255363/or-with-if-and-in-mongodb/68255564#68255564)

Comment from @Takis is not fully correct. When you create an index in MongoDB, then it indexes also documents where the field does not exist - unless you define a [Sparse Index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/core/index-sparse/)/[Partial Index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/core/index-partial/#std-label-index-type-partial). This behavior is different to most relational SQL databases.