# how to add a OR condition inside AND in $filter of mongodb aggregate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

Below is a block from my aggregate query,

```
{
          $addFields: {
            destinations: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$destinations",
                cond: {
                  $and: [
                    {
                      $or: [
                        {
                          "$$this.reported_at": {
                            $exists: false
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "$$this.reported_at": {
                            $eq: null
                          }
                        }
                      ],
                    },
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this.type",
                        1
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
```

which when run is throwing the below error

```
query failed: (InvalidPipelineOperator) Invalid $addFields :: caused by :: Unrecognized expression '$$this.reported_at'
```

Although `reported_at` is another property just like `type` inside the `destinations` array.
When I remove the object containing the OR condition, its not throwing an error.
Please help me resolve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't use `$$this.reported_at` like this way. This [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IochhUI2pcg) should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `$filter` `cond` field, you have to use the [expression operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#operator-expressions). Your query should be as below:

```
{
  $addFields: {
    destinations: {
      $filter: {
        input: "$destinations",
        cond: {
          $and: [
            {
              $or: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$this.reported_at",
                    undefined
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$this.reported_at",
                    null
                  ]
                }
              ],
              
            },
            {
              $eq: [
                "$$this.type",
                1
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `{ $eq: ["$$this.reported_at", undefined] }` is different to `{ "$$this.reported_at": { $exists: false } }`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68255363/or-with-if-and-in-mongodb/68255564#68255564

Comment: so what would be the exact solution @WernfriedDomscheit ?

Comment: As mentioned by @turivishal in the link, he says comparing it with null will be suffice

Comment: therefore this solution is supposed to work right?

Comment: Hi @WernfriedDomscheit, thanks for the feedback. However, I created this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PhWjZHgj17l), with `key2` is not existed. And when compare with `{ $eq: ["$key2", undefined] }`, this returns true.

Comment: Compare with [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rQc9bxGNbtf), then you see the difference. It might not be relevant for all cases but if you want to be exact then your condition give wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

This one should also work:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $addFields: {
         destinations: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$destinations",
               cond: {
                  $and: [                     
                     { $in: [{ $type: "$$this.reported_at" }, ['null', 'undefined', 'missing' ]] },
                     { $eq: ["$$this.type", 1] }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: I don't get it why you have added `$type: "$$this.reported_at"` ?

Comment: what does $type here indicate?

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/), it returns the type of the field value.

Comment: So will your solution solve the $exists problem which you shared as a concern below Yong 's Solution ?

Comment: If you need `{ "$$this.reported_at": { $exists: false } }` then you must use `{ $eq: [{ $type: "$$this.reported_at" }, 'missing' ] }` The array is used to avoid the `$or`