# Mongodb Atlas Search if the field exists

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas-search

I am new to mongodb using atlas search for my query. I want to return document based on a condition where if the field exists it should be false if the field does not exists it should return the document based on filters. Basically return the documents where field is `False` or where the field doesn't exist at all. If using find we can use like this
q['active'] = {'$ne': True}
How can we achieve same using atlas search

I tried using must, mustnot, if exists nothing seems to work

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68255363/or-with-if-and-in-mongodb/68255564#68255564

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [mustNot](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/compound/#options) clause with an equals operator worked for me:

```
[
  {
    $search: {
      index: <name of search index>,
      compound: {
        mustNot: [
          {
            equals: {
              path: <boolean field>,
              value: true,
            },
          },
        ],
        filter: [
          {
             // filter operations
          }
        ]
      },
    },
  },
]
```