In mongo pipeline, how to set the value of a field only if it already exists?
I have data in mongo:
{
    items:
    {
        cheese: {  version: 3 },
        egg: {  version: 23 }
    }
}

My service receives messages telling it the latest version of items.
If the latest cheese is version 4, I want the message handler to update the cheese version to 4.
   $set: { "items.cheese.version", 4 }

But, sometimes I receive a version number for an item I'm not interested in. If I receive the version of sausages, I don't want to write that because it doesn't exist.
I tried to write a condition to check for it and only update it if it exists, but mongo wants a value for the else branch. I tried $$REMOVE...
    $set: {
        "items.sausages.version": {
            $cond: {
                if: { $ne: ["$items.sausages", null] },
                then: "7",
                else: "$$REMOVE"
            }
        }

...but it still seems to add and the data ends up as:
{
    items:
    {
        cheese: {  version: 3 },
        egg: {  version: 23 },
        sausages: {}
    }
}

How can I only update an item if it already exists?

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68255363/or-with-if-and-in-mongodb/68255564#68255564

Would adding a filter, either in the query of an Update many or through a $match stage in the pipeline be a solution or do you rule that out for a reason?

One of the canonical ways to handle your case would be using $ifNull to catch 2 cases of the field does not exist or is equal to null. Then, chain up $cond with $mergeObjects to perform conditional update at items level.
db.collection.updateMany({
  // your query here
  
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "items": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": [
              {
                "$ifNull": [
                  "$items.sausages",
                  null
                ]
              },
              null
            ]
          },
          "then": "$items",
          "else": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$items",
              {
                "sausages": {
                  "version": 4
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground
